# hybris 5 Accelerator build fails on Eclipse but not on cmd

Tags: eclipse, build, compiler-errors, sap-commerce-cloud

I've installed a hybris 5 Commerce Accelerator B2C platform on my computer and imported the Eclipse projects from this platform into Eclipse, but some of the projects always have build errors. 
I can run **ant clean all** from the command line and build all projects successfully, but when I try cleaning and building my workspace from Eclipse I get this error for some of the projects:

```
Errors running builder 'Integrated External Tool Builder' on project 'ondemandcommon'.
Variable references non-existent resource : ${workspace_loc:/platform/resources/ant/beangen.xml}
Variable references non-existent resource : ${workspace_loc:/platform/resources/ant/beangen.xml}
```

The file `/platform/resources/ant/beangen.xml` in fact doesn't exist, but every project references this file from their **.externalToolBuilder/HybrisBeanGeneration.launch** file (see image below), so how come only a few projects can't be built?

[image]

Why won't these projects compile and what's the best way to fix this?

Comment: When you say "cleaning and building workspace from Eclipse", you mean the regular Project > Clean, Project > Build right? Or do you mean ant clean, ant all from within Eclipse?

Comment: Do you have platform in your workspace, and does the file `/platform/resources/ant/beangen.xml` exist? I haven't used hybris 5, but in 4 I was able to get it build in Eclipse by disabling the builders that don't work under Project > Properties > Builders. You didn't specify whether there are any errors or warnings in the code, but if so this document will help: https://wiki.hybris.com/display/general/Eclipse+errors+and+warnings

Comment: Yes, I mean the regular Project > Clean and then Eclipse builds them all automatically.

Comment: And no, the */platform/resources/ant/beangen.xml* in fact doesn't exist, but if I search for files containing this string, I see that every project references this in their *.externalToolBuilder/HybrisBeanGeneration.launch* file. I'll add the screen to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you mixed and matched platform/extensions from different releases? This was replaced by codegen.xml, try using this.

Alternatively, you very well may not need any of the cis/oms/ondemand extensions and can safely remove them.

Finally, you can disable the builder in eclipse and use the Ant build system. This is faster anyway.

Comment: Thanks. By changing the reference to codegen.xml, the build works.